# wpf text out of alignment in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

How to solve the text out of alignment in text box UI, but it was fine in copy to clipboard function to text file.

Thanks

[image]

**XAML：**

```
     <Grid>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" >
            <TextBox Name="txtServiceParameter" Width="550" Height="460" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="10, 10, 0, 0" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DefaultText}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>
            <Button Content="Copy to Clipboard" Width="150" Height="30" Margin="10, 10, 0, 0" Command="{Binding CopyToClipboardCommand}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

**C#:**

```
        defaultText += "Hello World - Class 1 Day 1 " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss");
        defaultText += Environment.NewLine;
        defaultText += Environment.NewLine;
        defaultText += Environment.NewLine;
        defaultText += "************************************************************************";
        defaultText += Environment.NewLine;
        defaultText += "Mathemathic Class";
        defaultText += Environment.NewLine;
        defaultText += "************************************************************************";
        defaultText += Environment.NewLine;
        defaultText += Environment.NewLine;
        defaultText += string.Format("{0, -3}, {1,-34}, {2}", "01", "Hello", "EEE910");
        defaultText += Environment.NewLine;
        defaultText += string.Format("{0, -3}, {1,-34}, {2}", "02", "Belo haha", "");          

        private void ExecuteCopyToClipboardCommand()
        {
          Clipboard.SetText(defaultText);
        }
```

Comment: can you show your `XAML` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the font family on the TextBox to one that is [Monospaced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).  The problem is the font you are using.  It does not have a fixed with for each character.

Comment: Hi Trevor, thanks for your reply. However, now it was fine display in textbox UI, but out of alignment in copy to clipboard text file.

Comment: What changes did you make?

Comment: change FontFamily to "Monospaced" and string format

Comment: @user1219310 I would suggest to set the same font for TextBox and notepad

Comment: @pushpraj hi, thanks for your suggestion. It works fine now, will take note on those minor things. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Normally With Spaces I mostly go for somekind of multiplication of white space characters Like If 10 white spaces are needed I multiply 1- with 2. It's not the best answer but it works